# Paypal integration scenarios

Tags: paypal

My client asked to integrate his e-commence web site with paypal. But he need to  do all credit card payments within his website(without moving to paypal site). e-commence web site is Java based application

When the order is placed, need to get some transaction number and continue  order. Client need to process his payment when the delivery is ready.

Is Payflow Pro suitable for this requirement?
What is the suitable method to do this kind of transaction?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process your payments within your site, but still using PayPal, then you need the subscriber service "Website Payments Pro".

The "Website Payments Standard" service is free (excluding transaction commission) but a buyer leaves your site, goes to paypal to pay, and then returns.

[PayPal Comparison Table - Standard vs. Pro](https://www.paypal-business.co.uk/accept-credit-cards-on-a-website-with-paypal/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

PayFlow Pro is also suitable for this; you can process PayPal payments as easily as credit card payments. (Note: in my opinion it's most appropriate for a large bulk of credit-card-only transactions.) If you're developing in Java, there's already an SDK for you to use -- I had to search everywhere for a suitable third-party API for PHP.